# How to input parameters into the downloaded setup.exe on the server side?

Tags: installation, windows-installer

What methods exist to include parameters (such as userid) into the setup.exe that users download from a server?

I'm looking for a way to give a customized installer to users that I already know (because they are logged in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your question tied with some technology/installation system? Or you are researching which installation system to use to achieve this functionality?

In NSIS there is option to append custom data to installer, see this article: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ReadCustomerData.

Answer (score 1):

- Maybe the easiest would be to send a setup_whateverparameter.exe filename instead of setup.exe...
- A smarter approach would probably be to store parameter into a ressource file which would be edited from command line with some tool like http://www.reseditor.com/
- Another one would be to generate a sort of INI file which would be packed with the original setup file using some installer software like Inno Setup (http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) and the original installer would be configured to check if some ini file exists in a temporary location, to just use its content to do specific tasks.

Other possibilities might exists, thoses are just the one which might be the most easy to implement.

Comment: Thank you. So option 3 would "wrap" around the original installer? Since we are signing the setup I was hoping to avoid re-signing and then getting caught in MS SmartScreen filter. I wonder if solution 1 would work fine because it's the same file, just different names. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I don't understand why renaming the file would not let you extract the userid from the filename. But it is not elegant for the user and might be bad in terms of security (what if the user rename the filename to some other working userid ?). You might have a look at [Ninite Website](http://ninite.com/help/how-ninite-works/) it is partially explained how they make uniques installer for every users... might give you ideas... good luck!

Comment: Btw why avoid re-signing ? i don't know which tools you are using but from command line, it shouldn't take more than 1 second to do

Comment: The main reason I wanted to avoid signing was that I assumed the hash would change and files would appear as individual files to download security filters like Microsoft SmartScreen.

Answer (score 0):

@elfrancesco hinted at Ninite and Patrick from Ninite got back to me with:

> We put the installer id in a segment of the .exe that doesn't get
>   included in the hash for the signature. So we just sign our loader
>   .exe once whenever we update it and then our web server drops in the
>   key for each download.